# set output in sympy for 2**3 * 2**4 = 2**7 instead of 128

Tags: python, sympy

I would like to set the output in sympy for expression `2**3 * 2**4 =` to  `2**7` instead of `128`. Is there an easy way?

Comment: sympy doesn't actually get involved in `2**3 * 2**4`. That's all Python integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This 'works' , tho may not be what you really want

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = Symbol('2')

>>> x
2

>>> x**3 * x**7
2**10


>>> z = x**3 * x**7

>>> z
2**10

>>> str(z)
'2**10'
>>> eval(str(z))
1024
```

added note (using suggestion by @if.... )

```
>>> two = Symbol('2', positive=True, integer=True)
>>> z = two**3 * two**7
>>> z
2**10

# a little cleaner perhaps than eval(str(z))
# but requiring you to remember the name `two`
>>> z.subs(two, 2)
1024
```

addition also 'works'

```
>>> two**3 + two**7
2**7 + 2**3

>>> ((two**3 + two**7)).subs(two,two)
2**7 + 2**3

>>> ((two**3 + two**7)).subs(two, 2)
136
```

Comment: Clever, I really like the way you think. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Very good idea. You could also use `two = Symbol('2')`. I'm not sure UTF-8 symbols like `②` are allowed, though

Comment: Just in case, define `two = Symbol('2', positive=True, integer=True)` so it retains some of the properties of the number 2 (can be relevant for other manipulations).

Answer (score 1):

Not really; you're asking to alter the default display of integers to be something outside the standard set of choices.  Regardless of the implementation details, this will boil down to you writing a function that accepts an integer and produces the exponent form you want to see, as a character string.